# Unable to get Sonar-Qube to analyze project

Tags: sonarqube, cobol

I have seen the other 2 appends and added sonar.languages=COBOL to my sonar-project.properties file to no avail.
I think it's basically more a case of not understanding the documentation (or the latter never having been "idiot tested"").

My problem is as follows. My properties file contains the following entries:-

```
# sonar.sources=../../mfuser/seb/source/
sonar.sources=C:/mfuser/SEB/Source
sonar.cobol.file.suffixes=cbl,cpy
sonar.cobol.copy.suffixes=cpy
#
sonar.languages=COBOL
```

When I run the sonar-scanner bat file, I'm seeing output like this:-

WARN File C:\mfuser\seb\source\vvira20.cbl is ignored. It is not located in module basedir c:\sonar-scanner\bin

To me this gives the **impression** that I can point to the directory containing my COBOL code, but **at the same time** the actual code HAS to be in c:\sonar-scanner\bin. Surely, that **can't** be the case? If it is, what is the point with the sonar.sources entry in the properties file?

In addition, onece I get this working, is there some way of specifying a parm/wild card so as to analyze SPECIFIC files. I tried sonar.sources=C:/mfuser/SEB/Source/vno* but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You ran sonar-scanner from its own directory instead of running from the project directory. As [the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) says:

> Run the following command from the project base directory
>
> sonar-scanner

This same documentation recommends to create the sonar-project.properties file at the root of the project directory and to set the "sonar.sources" property to a path which is relative to the sonar-project.properties file.

Alternatively, you may want to use the "sonar.projectBaseDir" property. See the [documentation for analysis parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-ProjectConfiguration.1).

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I've been experimenting and getting somewhere, but I still don't completely understand the parms and how they hang together. To keep it simple ...  the source code where I have my Cobol code is c:\a\b\c. I have copied the the sonar-project.properties file to this directory. In this file, I have specified sonar.sources as c:/a/b/c (I **still** don't understand why I have to include sonar.sources as being the SAME value as where the properties file is - isn't this tautology?). I included sonar.exclusions=VNO*.CBL (and **not** c:/a/b/c/vno*.cbl as I thought it should be)

Comment: My problem is that the cobol source code contains loads of COPY on copybooks in another directory completely (let's say in m:/d/e/f). I'm getting the message "Unable to find copybook 'xxxxx'  ....". How do I include m:/d/e/f in the properties file so they are found ?